# Swing Component communication

Tags: java, swing

i am building an algorithm simulation tool and I am struggling to get my mainframe class which instantiates and adds all the subcomponents to the JFrame to get the file system location of where the pseudocode is located (for the psuedocode panel.)

I have made every single algorithm have a string which details where the relevant text file information for each algorithm is.
I have a method which then takes the string when the algorithm is passed in and stores it into a string variable.
This string variable is then passed to the panel.
Unfortunately this is throwing a null pointer and I have been trying to debug this and can't get far.

```
  public class SortAnimator extends JFrame
{  
   private static final int VALUES_LENGTH = 30;
   private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 1200;
   private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 700;
   private PsuedocodePanel pseudoPanel;
   private Menu menu;
   private InformationPanel infoPanel;
   private String algoName;
   public String algoLocation;


   public SortAnimator(Sorter s) throws IOException
   {  
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      menu=new Menu();
      pseudoPanel=new PsuedocodePanel();
      ArrayComponent panel = new ArrayComponent();
      infoPanel= new InformationPanel();

      add(menu,BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(pseudoPanel,BorderLayout.WEST);
      add(infoPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
      setVisible(true);

      int[] values = new int[VALUES_LENGTH];
      for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
         values[i] = (int) (Math.random() * panel.getHeight());

      s.setValues(values);
      s.setPanel(panel);
      Thread t = new Thread(s);
      t.start();
      algoName=s.getAlgorithmName();
      algoLocation =s.getAlgorithmLocation();
       System.out.println(algoLocation);
      pseudoPanel.passFileLocation(algoLocation);
   }


}




    public class PsuedocodePanel extends JPanel{

        private JTextArea txtArea;
        private String textFile;
        private String fileLocation;


        public PsuedocodePanel() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

       setLayout(new BorderLayout());

       txtArea=new JTextArea();
       txtArea.setEditable(false);



         add(txtArea,BorderLayout.CENTER);
         FileReader fr = new FileReader(this.fileLocation);
         BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(fr);
         txtArea.read(reader,null);

         Dimension dim=getPreferredSize();//returns object
         System.out.println(getPreferredSize());
         dim.width=300;
         dim.height=75;
         setPreferredSize(dim);

           Border innerBorder=BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Algorithm Psuedocode");
           Border outerBorder=BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5);

           setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outerBorder,innerBorder));


        }

       public void passFileLocation(String algoLocation) {
            this.fileLocation= algoLocation;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `PsuedocodePanel` class creates a `FileReader` in its constructor, using `this.fileLocation`, but `fileLocation` will be null at that point in the code - see simplified code fragment below:

```
public class PsuedocodePanel extends JPanel{

    private String fileLocation;  // not initialised

    // constructor does not accept a fileLocation...
    public PsuedocodePanel() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    // ... so this.fileLocation is null here:
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(this.fileLocation);
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can get around this ?? I want to avoid doing the setting of the panel in the SortAnimator so I can separate the components.

Comment: Either modify the constructor so you can pass in the fileLocation, or wait until you have added a valid fileLocation before creating the FileReader. Or do the file reading outside of the PseudoPanel class, and just give it the text to display. Lots of choices....